# Error in unedited R.java file and no where else?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

Hi I have an app written that was working perfectly. I have it localised and I realised that one of my translations was incorrect so went into one of my string resource files and changed one of the text translations. After doing that I am now getting an error in my R.java file saying: Syntax error on token "Summary", delete this token. I'm just nervous to do this as I've always been told not to edit the R file. Has anyone encountered similar problems before?

Comment: Yes, don't do that. Go back to your `strings.xml` and make sure you didn't create an error then when fiddling with it.

Comment: It's possible that the resource compiler produces invalid java syntax. You should be fixing the input files that cause it to be happen instead of modifying the generated code. Post some additional details for specific help, such as error message, code that causes it and resource that generates the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though your generated R.java file has got itself in to a state

In your project, in the gen folder, delete the R.java file.

Next go to Project > Clean.

This should rebuild your project and recreate all the necessary links.

Comment: When R.java file is deleted it re-appears before  can clean the project, one string is giving the error but there are no errors in the string value files

Comment: Can you post the the whole line in the strings.xml that you changed? Update your original question.